# lots of 301 redirects with question marks htaccess issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have many many 301 redirects I need to set up.  I had a list set up like this and was hoping a copy and paste would do

```
Redirect 301 /?p=11781 http://www.example.com/page-a/
Redirect 301 /?p=11781 http://www.example.com/page-b/
Redirect 301 /?p=11781 http://www.example.com/page-c/
Redirect 301 /?p=11781 http://www.example.com/page-d/
etc...
```

After working on this for the whole day I realised its an issue with the question mark and that 301 redirect won't work. If it makes any difference I am using wordpress as well.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

Query_string is not part of match in Redirect directive, to match against query strings, you will need to use mod-rewrite :

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=11781$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/page-a/? [NC,L,R]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?p=11781 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/page-a/? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the target url is important as it discard the old query strings.